# mdframed around figure with threeparttable

Tags: floats, mdframed

I'm trying to draw a border around a figure (using mdframed) with a threeparttable. However, the size of the border is not adjusted correctly. How can I adjust the border to correctly wrap around the image? See an MWE below:

```
\documentclass[oneside,ngerman,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{mdframed,threeparttable}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{mdframed}
\caption{\textbf{Primary headaches}}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{abbildung_kopfschmerzen.png}
\begin{tablenotes}[para]
\textbf{Erlaeuterungen:} TTH=Kopfschmerzen vom Spannungstyp (Tension Type Headache)
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

The picture abbildung_kopfschmerzen.png: [image].
Btw, I couldn't add threeparttable as a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[oneside,ngerman,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\makeatletter % <---I think this is not needed
\usepackage{mdframed,threeparttable}
%\makeatother <---I think this is not needed
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{mdframed}{
\caption{\textbf{Primary headaches}}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{mdframed-1.png} %--- change [scale=0.6] to [width=1\textwidth] and I have renamed your figure for my convenience. You can use your name itself.
\begin{tablenotes}[para]
\textbf{Erlaeuterungen:} TTH=Kopfschmerzen vom Spannungstyp (Tension Type Headache)
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]